# Powershell parsing date from log

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to parse a log file to extract the date from the log file entry. I am able to find the line, but my parsing appears to not be converting the date.

```
$SBError = "DbConnection"
$SBWebPath = "E:\Temp\server.log"

$result = Get-Content $SBWebPath | Select-String $SBError -casesensitive | Select -last 1 | Out-String
$result | Select-String '####<(\S+ \S+, \S+ \S+ \S+) \S+>' | ForEach-Object {
    $DBdateTime = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value -as [DateTime]
    }
Write-Output $result
Write-Output $DBdateTime
```

server.log file contents:

```
####<Dec 9, 2018 2:59:08,082 AM EST> <Info> <HTTP> Data flowing fine.
####<Dec 9, 2018 2:59:08,085 AM EST> <Warning> <HTTP> framework.db.DbConnection.
```

Output from script:

```
####<Dec 9, 2018 2:59:08,085 AM EST> <Warning> <HTTP> framework.db.DbConnection.
```

Variable from $DBdateTime is not populating, I suspect due to incorrect or invalid parsing and/or inclusion of milliseconds in the log date.

I don't care about the milliseconds, only the Month day year hour minutes seconds and the AM/PM tag. Also don't care about EST but need to keep in mind that when server changes to EDT this value would exist in place of EST.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an empty value for `$DBDateTime` because PowerShell doesn't recognize the value of your captured group as a valid `DateTime`, so the string cannot be cast to that type. You need to actually parse it.

```
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$pattern = 'MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss,fff tt'

$DBDateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value, $pattern, $culture)
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for valid format strings.

Comment: You're right! It wasn't able to parse the date since it wasn't an exact date format match. I tested the log file without milliseconds and my original script worked, but by generating the pattern specific, was able to parse it exactly.